# Cómo utilizar != (diferente) con un array?

Tags: sql

Tengo que traer el resultado de una consulta, me explico mejor, los usuarios tienen asignados proyectos, pero se pueden postular en otros, Pero... como puedo hacer para que, en la vista de postulación, NO se le muestren los proyectos que ya tiene asignados?. Sé que con el operador !=, lo puedo hacer, pero que yo sepa solo se haría la validación de un registro solamente, pero como puedo hacer para que se valide si tiene más de un proyecto asignado? Espero darme a entender.. Gracias

Esta es mi relación entre proyecto y usuarios
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta queda dada:

```
select p.idproyecto, p.nombreProyecto, p.descripcion
from `proyecto` p 
where p.idproyecto != 1
```

donde se mostrarán los demás proyectos, en donde el usuario no está asignado, pero digamos que la clausula where quede `where p.idproyecto <> 1 and  p.idproyecto <> 7 o <>12`

Dependiendo de los proyectos que tenga el usuario, que muestre los que no tiene

Trabajo con PHP y mysql

Creo que primeramente tendría que consultar los proyectos donde el usuario está y después devolver los que no tiene, si estaría bien?

Comment: Buenas Yadira, pon un ejemplo de código que estés intentando y la estructura de tablas para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Yadira. Puedes mostrar la tabla(s) que tienes y la consulta que has intentado? Mira [ask] para más informacion. Un saludo

Comment: Lo primeo que te diría, es que si estas en SQL, no hay arrays. Muestra toda la info que puedas respecto del problema, ya que estas confundiendo tecnologías.

Comment: supongo que estas generando esa consulta mediante programación, es por eso que hablas de arrays, deberias aclara en cual lenguaje estas trabajando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De inicio, el operaror `<>` es el estándar ANSI SQL para indicar **`diferente de`**. Pero en este caso, requieres usar `NOT IN`:

Para mostrar los proyectos en los cuales no está asignado:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM proyecto
WHERE idproyecto NOT IN (
    SELECT 
        P.idproyecto
    FROM proyecto P
        INNER JOIN proyecto_usuarios PU
            ON P.idproyecto = PU.proyecto_idproyecto
        INNER JOIN usuarios U
            ON PU.usuarios_idusuarios = U.idusuarios
    WHERE U.idusuarios = --aquí va el id del usuario a buscar
)
```

Comment: si está bien, pero yo quisiera que se mostrarán los demás proyectos, en donde el usuario no está asignado digamos que la clausula where quede
where p.idproyecto <> 1 and where p.idproyecto <> 7 o  <>12.. Dependiendo de los proyectos que tenga el usuario, que muestre los que no tiene

Comment: @Yadira listo :)

Comment: esto es lo que buscaba.. gracias.. no creí que en las subconsultas existiera el NOT IN, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar un ciclo while:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $bd) or die("Ha sucedido un error.");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM proyectos INNER JOIN proyecto_usuarios ON proyectos.idproyecto != proyecto_usuarios.proyecto_idproyecto";

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die ("Se ha generado un error.");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data = $row['idproyecto'];
    $data1 = $row['nombreProyecto'];
}
```